# VI - Moving row below up to end of current row

Tags: linux, vim, text-editor, vi

How do I move below row up to end of current row?

No yanking, visual mode or pasting please.

Maybe this is for a Linux forum but I'm sure someone knows this. I've forgotten since I last used the VI editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `J` for *join*.

Comment: FYI (for those new to VIM) that's a capital `J` in command mode

Comment: @Asken you might want to know about `gJ` also which just deletes the newline without inserting any extra space like `J` does.

Comment: Good to know. Reverting from MS to unix/linux again... a bit rusty but it's slowly coming back. I need all the pointers I can get :)